# Fastest transfer from Vancouver Airport (YVR) to Whistler

Tags: airport-transfer, vancouver, yvr, whistler

I know that I can drive from YVR to Whistler in a rental car in about 2 hours (have done it many times before).

This time round, I'd like to take a shuttle.  I noticed that there are shuttle services online, but they all seem to make a stop in Vancouver city before heading out to Whistler. As a result, the shuttles seem to take 3 hours instead of 2.

Is there a direct, fast YVR->Whistler shuttle service available?

Comment: Not that I can find.

Comment: The quickest driving route from YVR to Whistler goes right through downtown Vancouver, so it's not like the extra shuttle stop is taking you a long way out of your way.  (It might still be nice to avoid the extra time to stop & load extra people and luggage, though.)

Comment: You can go by helicopter in about half an hour.  See for example http://www.whistler.com/getting-here/air/helicopter/.

Answer (score 4):

The [YVR/Whister Skylinx](http://www.pacificcoach.com/Bus-Coach-Travel/YVR-Whistler-Skylynx/YVR-to-Whistler) will take you straight from YVR to Whistler (and back) through Downtown Vancouver.

There is no bus that goes from YVR to Whistler without stopping or going through Downtown Vancouver.

According to this [information page](http://www.pacificcoach.com/Travel-with-PCL/Travelling-with-Pacific-Coach-Whistler):

> Departure location is located directly outside the terminal, close to our ticket counter.
>
> Departure Location: Whistler Bus Bay #10